# Using PHP to fill HTML select array can only display last element in array

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

Most of this is explained in the notes in the head of the HTML code below.
I do not want to use JavaScript, JQuery or any other methods. I want to do this using nothing but HTML and PHP if possible.
This displays as a one row table.
The code below uses some PHP code to fill a PHP array, then assign those elements as options in an HTML select list. That part is working. Also when I choose any option in the select list and post it with submit it posts OK, and on the page refresh the selected value is retained in the input field, which is what I want.
It's the variables that appear in the last column of the table that are always set to the last element in the select array (the last option in the list), as if the input variable is getting reset. I can sort of see this, but not sure how to fix it.
Been scratching my head for days and not finding other (none JavaScript) advice on the net. Not sure what part of this I'm not understanding.

The code is below. If you copy and past it to a working server it should be fully functional.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <!--
                    Notes for newer newbies than me.
                    In HTML a select list is an array, where the name of the array is the name assigned with
                    the name attribute in the select tag, and each option tag is an element in the array.
                    This code establishes a select list in HTML, and uses PHP to create another array and a 
                    FOR loop to fill the array with numerical values. This is more convenient than typing in
                    over 400 <option></option> values, and allows some flexibility to what may be in the select
                    list.
                    The HTML table has three cells: a label, the input field, and the result of the POST, which
                    just verifies what will later be saved into an XML file on the server.
                    
                    PROBLEM!: The select list fills perfectly. However, the result in the last cell of the table
                    (which is what will get saved to XML) is only always set to the last option in the list, which
                    is the last element in the select array. WHY?
                    Any value can be choosen in the option list and posted (and it appears to actually be POSTED
                    corretly). Why is the input variable not keeping its selected value past the line where
                    the option value is assigned in the select array (should be line 90 if you copy and paste
                    into your own editor.) The page if fully functional if you copy it to a server.
                    Thanks for any advice.
                -->
                <style>
                    table {border-collapse:collapse; border:5px solid black; padding:1em; width:100%; }
                    td {border:1px solid black;}
                    th {border:2px solid black;}
                    .colINPUTdisplay {background-color: #88CCCC;}
                    .colXMLdisplay {background-color: #00ffff; padding-right:1em;}
                    input, select {background-color: #000000; color: #00ff00; width:90%}
                </style>
            <head>
        <body>

        <form action="autofillSelectArrayTest.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <table style="border-color:blue; border-width:7px">
        <col />
        <col class="colINPUTdisplay" />
        <col class="colXMLdisplay" />
            <tr>
                    <?php 
                        if(isset($_POST["AllowedNumbers_input"])){$AllowedNumbers_input = $_POST["AllowedNumbers_input"];}
                        else{$AllowedNumbers = $AllowedNumbers_input = "ain't nothin been posted yet";}
                        
                        
                            
                                // Declare an array of allowed numbers.
                                $AllowedNumbersArray = array();
                                
                                // Fill the array.
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[0] = "1/32";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[1] = "1/16";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[2] = "1/8";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[3] = "1/4";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[4] = "1/2";
                                for($arrayIndex = 5; $arrayIndex <= 405; $arrayIndex++){$AllowedNumbersArray[$arrayIndex] = ($arrayIndex - 5);}
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[410] = "1/64";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[411] = "1/128";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[412] = "1/256";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[413] = "1/512";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[414] = "1/1024";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[415] = "1/10";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[416] = "1/100";
                                $AllowedNumbersArray[417] = "1/1000";
                        
                                //These were placed in the different places of the options to see what was displayed where on the page.
                                //Not being used on current page.
                                $A = "Value of Top Option";
                                $B = "Text of Top Option";
                                $C = "Value of Bottom Option";
                                $D = "Text of Bottom Option";
                    
                    
                    ?>
                <td>Dimension Selection: </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- NEXT LINE FOR DEBUGGING ONLY -->
                    <?php echo "This is at TOP of SELECT <br/>&#36;AllowedNumbers_input = " . $AllowedNumbers_input . "<br/>"; ?>
                    
                    <select name="AllowedNumbers_input">
                        <option selected="selected"><?php echo $AllowedNumbers_input; ?></option>
                        <!-- NEXT LINE FOR DEBUGGING ONLY -->
                        <option value=""><?php echo "<br/> This is UNDER &lt;option selected='selected'&gt; <br/>&#36;AllowedNumbers_input = " . $AllowedNumbers_input . "<br/>"; ?></option>
                                    
                        
                            <!-- looping through the array building option list -->
                            <?php foreach($AllowedNumbersArray as $AllowedNumbers_input){ ?>
                            
                            <!-- NEXT LINE FOR DEBUGGING ONLY -->
                            <option value=""><?php echo "<br/> This is UNDER the FOR EACH <br/>&#36;AllowedNumbers_input = " . $AllowedNumbers_input . "<br/>"; ?></option>
                            
        <!-- Problem is here --><option value="<?php echo $AllowedNumbers_input; ?>"><?php echo $AllowedNumbers_input; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            
                            <!-- NEXT LINE FOR DEBUGGING ONLY -->
                            <option value=""><?php echo "<br/> This is AFTER the OPTION <br/>&#36;AllowedNumbers_input = " . $AllowedNumbers_input . "<br/>"; ?></option>
                    </select>
                    
                        <!-- NEXT LINE FOR DEBUGGING ONLY -->
                        <?php echo "<br/> This is at BOTTOM of SELECT <br/>&#36;AllowedNumbers_input = " . $AllowedNumbers_input; ?>
                </td>                                    
                        <?php
                                if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/2"){$AllowedNumbers_num = .5;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/4"){$AllowedNumbers_num = .25;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/8"){$AllowedNumbers_num = .125;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/16"){$AllowedNumbers_num = 0.0625;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/32"){$AllowedNumbers_num = 0.03125;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/64"){$AllowedNumbers_num = 0.015625;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/128"){$AllowedNumbers_num = 0.0078125;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/256"){$AllowedNumbers_num = 0.00390625;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/512"){$AllowedNumbers_num = 0.001953125;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/1024"){$AllowedNumbers_num = 0.0009765625;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/10"){$AllowedNumbers_num = .1;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/100"){$AllowedNumbers_num = .01;}
                            else if($AllowedNumbers_input == "1/1000"){$AllowedNumbers_num = .001;}
                            else{$AllowedNumbers_num = $AllowedNumbers = $AllowedNumbers_input;}
                            
                        ?>
                        
                        <?php 
                            $AllowedNumbers = $AllowedNumbers_input;
                            $AllowedNumbers_str =  "{" . $AllowedNumbers  . "}";
                        ?>
                    
                <td class="alignNumber"><?php echo $AllowedNumbers_str . "<br/>"; echo $AllowedNumbers . "<br/>"; echo $AllowedNumbers_input; ?></td>
            </tr> 
            
            <tr>
            <!-- Submit Form Button -->
                <td class="center" colspan="3"><input class="center" width="100%" type="submit" value="Click To POST selected number"></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>

        </form>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the variable `$AllowedNumbers_input`, that you previously stored the POST value in, by doing `foreach($AllowedNumbersArray as $AllowedNumbers_input)`. In that loop, each item from the array will be assigned to `$AllowedNumbers_input` (so that you have access to one single item inside your loop body via the variable name), and after the loop is done, it retains the last value.

Comment: OK, Think I may have found an answer. Will post later if it works with all the other existing code - as the real form is very large. In the <option> embedded in the foreach loop I added a variable called $AllowedNumbersOption for the purpose of filling the select array, but left the <option> under the <select> tag - used on the page to actually select an option - as is: $AllowedNumbers_input. This seems to have cured what I believe was overwriting the input. Will post an official answer later.